# How to convert Int of Array values to Double using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

In myscenario, I am trying to add zero with point before array of Integer value. For example my array of integer values like `50` but before passing to AMProgress I need to add  like `0.50`. If supposed `0.100` came need to change like `1`. How to achieve this?

**My Code Below**

```
let data : [Int] = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,4,23,54,100]    
Required output: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc,...
```

Comment: Look for `NSNumberFormatter` For the rest, it's a simple multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let data : [Int] = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,4,23,54,100]

    let convertedData = data.map { Double($0)/100}
```

Output:

```
[0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.04, 0.23, 0.54, 1.0]
```

Comment: Sorry, but something as simple as `Double(value)/100` should work without any special handling. Handling cases like these with condition checks is not a proper approach

Comment: @LokSN I did this because what if the value is 1 .. 1/100 will make it 0.01 . right ?? I thought the question said to add `0.`  to a number... **UPDATED THE ANSWER**

Comment: Oh, i get you. The question is ambiguous but I'm guessing that the OP wants the actual progress within 0.0 - 1.0 based on the percentage

Comment: @LokSN yeah right. I have updated my answer based on that. can you take back your downvote now? :)

Comment: I have already, don't even worry about it ;-)